# Angular: Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(entryComponent)

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I am getting this error while trying to create a new component inside of my nx, angular project. This is an angular project that I migrated into an nx project using this command: `ng add @nrwl/workspace`

I have attempted to update angular to 12, but that does not seem to help at all.
I do see the error points out that my `"Style":"css"` is css, I think this is where the issue is as the entire project's style is scss.

I have been at this for about a week now and have had no luck at all figuring out why this is happening...

Here is the exact error:

```
Node.js version v15.10.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
Your global Angular CLI version (12.0.2) is greater than your local version (11.0.6). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
InvalidInputOptions [Error]: Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"path":"apps/nobleui-angular/src/app","project":"nobleui-angular","name":"test","displayBlock":false,"inlineStyle":false,"inlineTemplate":false,"changeDetection":"Default","style":"css","type":"Component","skipTests":false,"flat":false,"skipImport":false,"skipSelector":false,"export":false,"entryComponent":false}
Errors:

  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(entryComponent).
    at MapSubscriber.project (/home/kevin/source/repos/cropwatch/web/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/schema-option-transform.js:32:27)
    at MapSubscriber._next (/home/kevin/source/repos/cropwatch/web/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/map.js:49:35)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/kevin/source/repos/cropwatch/web/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._next (/home/kevin/source/repos/cropwatch/web/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/throwIfEmpty.js:44:26)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/kevin/source/repos/cropwatch/web/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at TakeSubscriber._next (/home/kevin/source/repos/cropwatch/web/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/take.js:54:30)
    at TakeSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/kevin/source/repos/cropwatch/web/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/home/kevin/source/repos/cropwatch/web/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:93:26)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber._next (/home/kevin/source/repos/cropwatch/web/node_modules/rxjs/internal/innerSubscribe.js:27:21)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/kevin/source/repos/cropwatch/web/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18) {
  errors: [
    {
      keyword: 'additionalProperties',
      dataPath: '',
      schemaPath: '#/additionalProperties',
      params: [Object],
      message: 'should NOT have additional properties'
    }
  ]
}
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"path":"apps/nobleui-angular/src/app","project":"nobleui-angular","name":"test","displayBlock":false,"inlineStyle":false,"inlineTemplate":false,"changeDetection":"Default","style":"css","type":"Component","skipTests":false,"flat":false,"skipImport":false,"skipSelector":false,"export":false,"entryComponent":false}
Errors:

  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(entryComponent).
```

and here is my angular.json (updated by nx):

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false,
    "defaultCollection": "@nrwl/angular"
  },
  "defaultProject": "nobleui-angular",
  "schematics": {
    "@nrwl/angular:application": {
      "linter": "eslint",
      "unitTestRunner": "jest"
    },
    "@nrwl/angular:library": {
      "linter": "eslint",
      "unitTestRunner": "jest"
    },
    "@nrwl/angular:component": {}
  },
  "projects": {
    "nobleui-angular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "apps/nobleui-angular",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/nobleui-angular/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/nobleui-angular",
            "index": "apps/nobleui-angular/src/index.html",
            "main": "apps/nobleui-angular/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "apps/nobleui-angular/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/nobleui-angular/tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "apps/nobleui-angular/src/favicon.ico",
              "apps/nobleui-angular/src/assets",
              "apps/nobleui-angular/src/.htaccess"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "apps/nobleui-angular/src/styles.scss",
              "apps/nobleui-angular/src/assets/scss/style.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/nobleui-angular/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/nobleui-angular/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "nobleui-angular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "nobleui-angular:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "nobleui-angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "apps/nobleui-angular/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "apps/nobleui-angular/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/nobleui-angular/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "apps/nobleui-angular/karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "apps/nobleui-angular/src/favicon.ico",
              "apps/nobleui-angular/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": ["apps/nobleui-angular/src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "apps/nobleui-angular/tsconfig.app.json",
              "apps/nobleui-angular/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "nobleui-angular:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "nobleui-angular:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "nobleui-angular-e2e": {
      "root": "apps/nobleui-angular-e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "apps/nobleui-angular-e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "nobleui-angular:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "nobleui-angular:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "apps/nobleui-angular-e2e/tsconfig.json",
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "api-gateway": {
      "root": "apps/api-gateway",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/api-gateway/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:build",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/api-gateway",
            "main": "apps/api-gateway/src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/api-gateway/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["apps/api-gateway/src/assets"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "inspect": false,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/api-gateway/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/api-gateway/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "api-gateway:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/api-gateway/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/apps/api-gateway"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/api-gateway/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "api-interfaces": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "libs/api-interfaces",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/api-interfaces/src",
      "prefix": "nobleui-angular",
      "architect": {
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/libs/api-interfaces"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/api-interfaces/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "libs/api-interfaces/src/**/*.ts",
              "libs/api-interfaces/src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "api-token": {
      "root": "apps/api-token",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/api-token/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:build",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/api-token",
            "main": "apps/api-token/src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/api-token/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["apps/api-token/src/assets"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "inspect": false,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/api-token/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/api-token/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "api-token:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/api-token/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/apps/api-token"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/api-token/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "api-sensors": {
      "root": "apps/api-sensors",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/api-sensors/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:build",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/api-sensors",
            "main": "apps/api-sensors/src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/api-sensors/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["apps/api-sensors/src/assets"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "inspect": false,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/api-sensors/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/api-sensors/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "api-sensors:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/api-sensors/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/apps/api-sensors"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/api-sensors/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "api-user": {
      "root": "apps/api-user",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/api-user/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:build",
          "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/api-user",
            "main": "apps/api-user/src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/api-user/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["apps/api-user/src/assets"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "inspect": false,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/api-user/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/api-user/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "api-user:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/api-user/**/*.ts"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
          "outputs": ["coverage/apps/api-user"],
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/api-user/jest.config.js",
            "passWithNoTests": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only entry I found on google about this was this question: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67780436/invalidinputoptions-error-when-adding-component-to-angular-11) However, this the answer provided here doesn't seem to be correct as the project can accept new components alone. I don't think an upgrade is what is needed.